# "In both an accurate and commercial" vs "in a both accurate and commercial"

Tags: word-order

Which of these two sentences is (more) correct?

> 1. I can translate your texts in both an accurate and commercial way.
> 2. I can translate your texts in a both accurate and commercial way.

Comment: Avoid the whole question: *I can translate your texts in a way that is both accurate and commercial.*

Comment: B is grammatically okay, but somewhat awkward. A is ungrammatical: ‘both’ requires two balanced concepts to govern, and you would have to repeat the indefinite article to balance these two. A would mean there are two different ways you can translate the texts, though: an accurate way, and a commercial way. If B is the meaning you want, a better solution would be, “I can translate your texts in a way that is both accurate and commercial”. [Edit: @Peter—hah, beat me to it. Great minds think alike!]

Comment: @Janus: we both come to the same conclusion, but I would have said that B was also ungrammatical.

Comment: No hard feelings, but one thing is for sure: if you used either sentence, I would take my translation business elsewhere.

Comment: P.S. @Peter and Janus. Since you picked up the wording without raising an eyebrow, let me ask you: what *is* "a commercial way"? That combination of words makes no sense to me. How do I go about translating something in a commercial way, and what do incommercial ways look like?

Comment: Translating something in a commercial way means, I assume, that the translation will sell (or at least will  make money).

Comment: @RegDwigнt, it's so funny that you took for granted that translation is only possible into English!

Answer (score 1):

A is more correct, but as another reader comments, you need to repeat the indefinite article to balance the phrases after "both." "I can translate your texts in both an accurate and a commercial way" is grammatically correct. The meaning of the sentence is ambiguous, though, because the meaning of translating "in a commercial way" isn't clear.